# Correspondance between ring homomorphisms and algebras over rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is a remark in Exercise 1.3.D in [Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf):

> Recall: the data of "an $A$-algebra $B$" and “a ring map $A \to B$ are the same.)

I tried to make sense of this and tried the following:

- If we have a ring homomorphism $\varphi: A \to B$, we obtain an $A$-algebra $B_\varphi = (B,+,\cdot,\times)$ whose scalar multiplication $\times$ is defined by $$ a \times b := \varphi(a) \cdot b \ $$
  (here, $+$ resp. $\cdot$ stand for the ring addition resp. multiplication in $B$).
- If we have an $A$-algebra $B$, we obtain a ring homomorphism $\varphi_B: A\to B$ by setting $$\varphi_B(a) := a \times 1_B$$
  (here, $1_B$ stands for the multiplicative identity element in $B$).

These two maps are inverses of each other if my calculations are correct. Could you please confirm if my approach is correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need help here. But I would like to say for a $k$-algebra we ask that $k$ commutes with $A$ (we need it to consider the polynomials with coefficients in $k$ and variable in $A$) if it doesn't commute the term $k$-module is more adapted. For example quaternions are a $\Bbb{C}$-module but only a $\Bbb{R}$-algebra.

Comment: @reuns: How can $k$ commute with $A$? The only operations which we have are addition ($A \times A \to A$), ring multiplication ($A \times A \to A$) and scalar multiplication ($k \times A \to A$). And $k$ is not necessary a subset of $A$, so I do not understand what you mean by commutative. Besides, I also do not see how your remark is related to my post.

Comment: For a $k$-module we don't need that $A$ has a multiplication, for a $k$-algebra we need that $(k_1.a_1) (k_2.a_2) = (k_1k_2).(a_1a_2)$ (where $.$ is the $k$-module action, if $A$ is an algebra then $\phi(k_1)= k_1.1_A$ is a unital ring homomorphism $\phi :k \to A$). In other words we need that $\forall b\in\phi(k),a\in A, ab=ba$. In your text the rings are assumed unital and commutative so this condition is satisfied.

Comment: I tried to think about it but cannot see how the commutativity of the ring comes into play. If $b \in \phi(k)$, then $b = \phi(x)$ for some $x \in k$. Then $$a b = a \phi(x) = a (x.1_A) = x.(a 1_A) = x.(1_A a) = (x.1_A) a = \phi(x) a = ba.$$ The main thing I used here is that the ring is unitary and the definition of $1_A$. And I also do not see how $ab = ba$ is directly related to $(k_1 . a_1) (k_2.a_2) = (k_1 k_2) . (a_1 a_2)$.

Comment: ??? You have used that the $k$ action commutes with the multiplication by $a$. Why don't you try with the quaternions.